AutoMapper Value Resolver using DI
I haven't seen anything quite like this scenario, so I thought I'd ask the big brains :)
Environment: .Net 6, preloading a zip code table for performance into a Dictionary<string, object>, GetProperty below is an object extension I have for retrieving properties from a generic object.
The injection of the dictionary into the resolver is not working properly and I get an exception
"Error mapping types.  Destination Member: State"
public class Object1
{
    public string Zip5 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string Zip5 { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class ZipCode
{
    public string Zip5 { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    // other fields
}

IDictionary<string, ZipCode> zipcodes = new Dictionary<string, ZipCode>();
// Preload from database

CreateMap<object1, object2>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.State, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>());

public class MyResolver : IValueResolver<object, object, string>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, ZipCode> zipcodes;
    public MyResolver(IDictionary<string, ZipCode> zipcodes)
    {
        this.zipcodes = zipcodes;
    }
    public string Resolve(object source, object destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var zip5 = source.GetProperty("Zip5")?.ToString() ?? "";
        if (zipcodes.ContainsKey(zip5)
            return zipcodes[zip5].State;
        else
            return "";
    }
}


This doesn't seem to have anything to do with AM. DI works the same, wherever you do the injection.

Ok, DI may be a red herring here because I don't understand how to get the resolver to use the Dictionary Lookup.  For performance, there should be a single instance of the Dictionary for the life of the application.
